# Failing Android Service on Motorola Droid line

Tags: android, motorola-droid

I have an Android Service that parses large xml files and stores the data in a sqlite database. This architecture has run without too many problems, but recently there has been trouble on several different models of Motorola phones.

Here is the error:

```
    12-05 08:41:23.708: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(19152): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27360 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/com.dsndata.sds2mobile.status.activities/databases/jobs.db
12-05 08:41:23.708: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(19152): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27360 - "" errno=24 path=/data/data/com.dsndata.sds2mobile.status.activities/databases, db=/data/data/com.dsndata.sds2mobile.status.activities/databases/jobs.db
12-05 08:41:23.708: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(19152): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = statement aborts at 28: [INSERT INTO JOBNAMETechnip_All_x_x_x_x_units_submaterial(Main,Description,Grade,Weight,Piecemark,Length,Finish,MaterialType,MemberGuid,ManufacturingGUID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)] , db=/data/data/com.dsndata.sds2mobile.status.activities/databases/jobs.db
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152): Error inserting Main=0 Description=FB11GAx1 Grade=310SS Weight=0.481653435459 Piecemark=FB63 Length=14.3125 Finish=None MaterialType=Flat bar MemberGuid=1f3e95c0-7289-4132-9218-296fcfcbcaad ManufacturingGUID=55d0399a-782d-476d-8619-5612c466905c
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: error code 14: unable to open database file
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1827)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1700)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.provider.JobProvider.insert(JobProvider.java:164)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:189)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.xml.MobileParser.endElement(MobileParser.java:494)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderAdapter.endElement(XMLReaderAdapter.java:353)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.endElement(ExpatParser.java:156)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendChars(Native Method)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:497)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:484)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:309)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:267)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderAdapter.parse(XMLReaderAdapter.java:223)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:359)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.xml.MobileParser.parse(MobileParser.java:172)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.xml.MobileParser.parse(MobileParser.java:144)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.services.ImportService$ServiceWorker.run(ImportService.java:58)
12-05 08:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(19152):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-05 08:41:23.802: W/System.err(19152): android.database.SQLException: Failed to insert row into content://com.dsndata.sds2mobile.jobprovider/JOBNAMETechnip_All_x_x_x_x_units/submaterial/55d0399a-782d-476d-8619-5612c466905c
12-05 08:41:23.802: W/System.err(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.provider.JobProvider.insert(JobProvider.java:187)
12-05 08:41:23.802: W/System.err(19152):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:189)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.xml.MobileParser.endElement(MobileParser.java:494)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderAdapter.endElement(XMLReaderAdapter.java:353)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.endElement(ExpatParser.java:156)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendChars(Native Method)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:497)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:484)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:309)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:267)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderAdapter.parse(XMLReaderAdapter.java:223)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:359)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.xml.MobileParser.parse(MobileParser.java:172)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.xml.MobileParser.parse(MobileParser.java:144)
12-05 08:41:23.809: W/System.err(19152):    at com.dsndata.sds2mobile.services.ImportService$ServiceWorker.run(ImportService.java:58)
12-05 08:41:23.817: W/System.err(19152):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The strangest part, is that the xml parsing and storing works up to a point, then fails with error 14.

Also, there are many logs of this message:

```
2-05 08:39:15.700: D/ActivityThread(19152): Loading provider com.dsndata.sds2mobile.jobprovider: com.dsndata.sds2mobile.provider.JobProvider
```

Which doesn't show up on other brands of devices.

I have asked Google and not found anything useful. Has anyone else had this problem? Or at least something similar which might be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am Lunchbox's dev partner on this project.

As we continue with the testing, we are finding that we think this only occurs on Motorola devices, running Motorola's Android skin, also running Android 4.0 and up. The error does not happen on a Xoom tablet running the latest version of Jellybean, nor does it happen on a Motorola Photon running Motorola's skin and Android 2.3.5.

Comment: We've experience the same database exception here where I work.  No solution up to now.